# Tkinter listbox to combobox

Tags: python, tkinter

Actually, I have two questions. First question is ,How to replace a listbox with an combobox? The second question,I want the user to see the dic key but a function to use the value,How can I do that?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def calculate():
    a = l1.get('active')
    b = si1.get('active')
    tulemus = a+b
    Label(aken, text="answer: %.2f" % tulemus).grid(row=7, column=5)

aken = Tk()
aken.title('kalk')
aken.configure(background='#E6F3FE')
aken.geometry("420x200")

l1 = ttk.Label(aken, text="2 ", background="#E6F3FE")
l1.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(N, W, ))

l1 = Listbox(aken, height=1)
l1.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(N, W, E))

pr = {50: 60, 80: 46}
for i in pr:
    l1.insert(END, i)

si1 = ttk.Label(aken, text="1 ", background="#E6F3FE")
si1.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(N, W, ))

si1 = Listbox(aken, height=1)
si1.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(N, W, E))

pr = {50: 60, 80: 46, 8: 6}
for i in pr:
    si1.insert(END, i)

nupp = ttk.Button(aken, text="Calculate", command=calculate)
nupp.grid(column=1, row=7, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(N, S, W, E))

aken.mainloop()
```

Comment: did you even try to convert it to a combo box or do you just want to be told how to do it ?

Comment: Graphic interface is new to me, and I just do n't know how to do it......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the: [Combobox documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/tkinter.ttk.html#combobox)

In your case you could define `l1` as:

```
# Read-only combobx with choice values (50, 80)
l1 = ttk.Combobox(aken, values=[50, 80], state='readonly')
# Select the first item of the combobox by default
l1.current(0)
```

Then in your `calculate()` method:

```
def calculate():
    # Get current value selected in the combobox and convert it to float
    a = float(l1.get())
    ...
```